# How to change font color of the text(Given by the user) in input-box in HTML-CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, colors

HTML code:-

```
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></p>
```

CSS code:-

```
.main-header input
{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #5f5fb0;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: #fff;
}
```

I want to change the color to #fff(white) of the text given by the user in the `input` box on the webpage. In this project, I am using HTML and CSS. I had tried very much but I can not make the color white.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the color to the `input` tag's selector itself the `color` property

```css
input {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this.
You can change it to `.main-header input`.

```css
input[type="text"]
{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #5f5fb0;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background: black;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></p>
```

Comment: And change "background-color: transparent;".

Comment: Thank you, Sir, I have tried your code and it works properly

Comment: You are welcome. can you approve my answer? Thank you. ;)